# How to Change Variable Value in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

**i'm learning, EntityFramework.**

```
  using (YonetimDBEntities YonetimDB = new YonetimDBEntities())
        {
            var Sorgu = from c in YonetimDB.iletisim
                        select new {
                            c.id,
                            c.FullName,
                            c.Email,
                            c.Subject,
                            c.Date,
                            c.Status
                               };

              // Status Value 1 or 0


            myRepeaterName.DataSource = Sorgu.ToList();
            myRepeaterName.DataBind();

        }
```

My c.Status value 1 or 0 , i want control my status value and write in my Repeater Line,

Example

```
if (c.Status == 1) {  c.StatusString = "Active"; }else{  c.StatusString = "Deactive"; }
```

Can i read and how to write my Repeater Line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating an anonymous type (new {}) you can basically add whatever you want into it.

Try this:

```
var Sorgu = from c in YonetimDB.iletisim
                        select new {
                            c.id,
                            c.FullName,
                            c.Email,
                            c.Subject,
                            c.Date,
                            c.Status,
                            StatusString = c.Status == 1 ? "Active" : "Deactive"
                               };
```

A better solution is actually this:

```
public class sorguModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusText {
        get{
            return this.Status == 1 ? "Active" : "Deactive";
        }
    }
}

var sorguList = YonetimDB.iletisim
                .select( i => new sorguModel { 
                            Id = c.id,
                            FullName = c.FullName,
                            Email = c.Email,
                            Subject = c.Subject,
                            Date = c.Date, // ASSUMING THE DATE IS A PROPER DATE FORMAT
                            Status = c.Status})
                .ToList();
```

Comment: it's working.

Thanks For Help :)

i'm trying write with a class.
can i write if condition or switch in select without class.

Comment: Inline Conditional - Yes
I have never personally tried to put a switch in there, give it a go and let us know if it works.